# Print total amount in crystal report just down of items list

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to print invoice in crystal report . I put total amount in page footer and items 
in details section but when it is printing 10 items the total is printing at the end of page.

How can I print the total just down of the item list?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the report footer for the total amount not the page footer.